# jQuery get/select element by property value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Is there a way to get/select an element by it's property value, just as it is possible with the attribute values:

```
$('[attribute="value"]')
```

For example, I'd set a property using jQuery like this:

```
$('#foo').prop('my-property', 'value');
```

and then I'd like to find an element which has property `'my-property'` and it has value `'value'`.

Comment: Any particular property?

Comment: Do you mean like an Input value?

Comment: Any particular element?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, there isn't anything exposed at the selector level that can select by *property* value, just (as you know) attribute value.

Some properties are reflections of attributes, which means that setting the property sets the attribute, which allows you to use attribute selectors. For instance, an `input` element's `defaultValue` property is a reflection of its `value` attribute (which its `value` property is not).

Otherwise, you select by what you can and use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) to filter the resulting list to only the elements you actually want.

Re your edit:

> For example, I'd set a property using jQuery like this:
>
> ```
> $('#foo').prop('my-property', 'value');
> ```

No, there's no way to select by that property directly, you'd need something like my `filter` suggestion above:

```
var list = $("something-that-gets-you-close").filter(function() {
    return this["my-property"] == "value";
});
```

You might consider using `data-*` attributes instead:

```
$("#foo").attr("data-my-property", "value");
```

then

```
var list = $("[data-my-property='value']");
```

to select it (the inner quotes are optional for values matching the definition of a [CSS identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)). Note that attribute values are always strings.

Beware: There's a persistent misconception that jQuery's `data` function is a simple accessor for `data-*` attributes. It is not. It manages a data cache associated with the element by jQuery, which is *initialized* from `data-*` attributes but disconnected from them. In particular, `.data("my-property", "value")` would not let you find that later via a `[data-my-property=value]` selector.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer! Actually this is what I thought myself, too, after searching it on the internet. Anyway, now it's here on SO as well.